# Have java drive bys stopped working?

Tags: java, drive-by-download

I don't hear or read about Java Drive Bys ([DBD](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive-by-Download)) these days. Up until last year we were always warned against java drive by threats. What happened? Have they become obsolete these days?

Edit: To be more clear, I was asking if JDB's are still a threat and if they even work to begin with. Stephane gave me the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are evidences that malware authors are [moving from Java to Flash](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/04/27/ninety_percent_of_java_blackhats_now_finger_flash/) due to the fact that [IE](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/ie_tips.xml), [FireFox](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/firefox_java.xml) and [chome](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml) now all blocks unpatched versions of the JVM plugin from running (chrome blocks the in-browser java browser alltogether unless the user manually enables [NPAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI)).

This move has reduced the usefulness of Java exploits (and therefore, DBD). And since Flash (and friends) are still [fat, juicy target](https://www.gfi.com/blog/most-vulnerable-operating-systems-and-applications-in-2014/), maleware operator are following the path of the least resistance.